# Schedule of Run Command in AWS Systems Manager

Tags: amazon-systems-manager, aws-ssm, runcommand

In my AWS account, under AWS Systems Manager > Run Command, I can see nothing under Commands tab but there are a lot of tasks records under Command history. I can see which document these tasks run on. However, I have no idea why there are so many command history here and why some tasks run daily. Where are these commands configured and how are they set to run daily?

Answer (score 1):

See If a run command document is associated with,

1. Maintenance window under  AWS Systems Manager
2. State Manager Association under  AWS Systems Manager. In the command history, the comment section will be filled with "Apply association with ... "
3. Event rules under AWS Cloudwatch.

You can also look at the cloudtrail logs to see if any specific service started the Run Command execution ( eg. Lambda ).

Answer (score 0):

SSM > Create Maintainance Windows > Register Run command task

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).